# How to create a memory leak in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, memory

I'm trying to create a memory leak example in AngularJS. I use ChromeDev Tool but it seems difficult to find. This is one of my demos:

```
.directive('myDirectiveLeak', function () {
    return {
      replace: 'AE',
      template:'<div><input type = "text"></div>',
      link: function(scope,element){
        element.bind('click',function(e){
          element.datepicker(); /// I add a JQuery plugin
        });
      }
    };
```

Some websites show this code causes a memory leak. After forced GC, I still didn't see any memory leak. I think AngularJS which is a product of Google has done something to avoid memory leak already. Can you give me a typical example in AngularJS. Thank you!

Comment: @ExpertSystem Because AngularJS team want to improve performance of their product. If you use available events of AngularJS, they will be automatically destroyed when a corresponding scope is destroyed. But if use a Jquery plugin which has its own events, angularjs won't do, so we have to do ourself

Answer (score 0):

If you use this directive inside an ngRepeat where entries are regularly replaced, you will notice the memory leak. It's caused by the binding to the 'click' event. You have to unbind this event on destroying the directive:

```
.directive('myDirectiveLeak', function () {
    return {
      replace: 'AE',
      template:'<div><input type = "text"></div>',
      link: function(scope,element){
        var clicked = function(e){
          element.datepicker(); /// I add a JQuery plugin
        };
        element.bind('click', clicked);
        scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
          element.unbind('click', clicked);
        });
      }
    };
```

Reason is that because of the attached event, your directive stays in memory, although it's been removed within the ngRepeat which would recreate the DOM every time you change the list.'

PS: You could use 'track by' to track changes in an ngRepeat directive. For more info, check the [documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/docs/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have read ngRepeat diretive in AngularJS and I have seen it used $destroy() to clean up references and jquery event. So I don't know if we need use element.unbind here?  https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.0-rc.3/src/ng/directive/ngRepeat.js#L338